# Django `filter` and `Q` query methods with ANDed conditions not working

Tags: python, django, filter, logical-operators

I want to filter a model with with 2 conditions with "and" logic. I have tried using chain filters and Q method too but not getting the desired result. Its works as "or" logic. Please help.

I tried:

```
Products.objects.order_by('Name').values('Name', 'UPC', 'ProductPrice', 'SubDeptNumber', 'CategoryNumber', 'FirstCompPrice', 'SecondCompPrice', 'ThirdCompPrice').filter(Name_icontains="Land", UPC_contains="15")
```

and

```
p = Products.objects.order_by('Name').values('Name', 'UPC', 'ProductPrice', 'SubDeptNumber', 'CategoryNumber', 'FirstCompPrice', 'SecondCompPrice', 'ThirdCompPrice').filter(Name_icontains="Land")

result = p.filter(UPC_contains="15")
```

I get results showing all the records with UPC which contains "15" even if name doesn't contain "Land"

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You only need to pass both conditions as keyword arguments on the same filter since they will be [**ANDed** by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
Entry.objects.filter(
    headline__startswith='What',
    pub_date__gte=datetime.date.today()
)
```